# Что неправильно в предложении?

Tags: лексика

Представленная на выставке репродукция картины 17 века была выполнена современным художником.

Comment: Выставка репродукций? Допустим. Но репродукция — не то, чем занимается художник. «17 века»... Не солидно. Традиционно будет — XVII в.

Answer (score 3):

**А.** Из словаря [Ефремовой](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):
**репроду́кция**
**I.** *ж.*
1. Воспроизведение какого-л. изображения – рисунка, картины, печатного текста и т. п. – средствами фотографии или полиграфии.
2. Картина, рисунок, текст, воспроизведенные таким способом.

Репродукция – это никак не работа художника.

**Б.** В русском языке римские цифры используются для указания порядковых номеров монархов (Екатерина II, Карл XII), иногда для нумерации томов и разделов книг, для маркировки циферблатов часов, обозначения Олимпийских игр и конференций, написания веков (чаще, чем арабские).
Римские цифры по своей значимости считаются более весомыми.

Я бы написала так:
**Представленная на выставке копия картины XVII века была выполнена современным художником.**

[Из "Нового полного биографического словаря русских художников":
МАТВЕЕВА, Евгения Кузминична (? – после 1883) – живописец. ***Представлена*** в Государственном Русском музее **копией картины** Рафаэля «Мадонна с младенцем и Иосифом».]

[Подлинник, копия, репродукция](http://chgal.ssu.samara.ru/Slovar%20iskusstv/slovar%20kopia.html) – здесь есть интересная информация.

Comment: И ещё - копию не выполняют, а делают. " Представленная на выставке копия картины XVII века была  сделана современным художником".

Comment: Попробую не согласиться. ВЫПОЛНИТЬ – 2. обычко кратк. страд, прич. прош. **Изготовить, создать, сделать.**  http://www.вокабула.рф/словари/бтс/выполнить 1. ... **копия была выполнена** при жизни Вермеера. 2. Не позднее 1617 года с работы Дюрера нюрнбергским художником Иобстом Харрихом **была выполнена копия** для оставшегося во Франкфурте алтаря. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алтарь_Геллера

Comment: @Людмила В Нацкорпусе: "копия  сделана" — 24 раза, "копия выполнена" — 6 раз, то есть тоже допустимо.

Answer (score 2):

Речь идет, вероятно, **о копии картины.**

РЕПРОДУКЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. re- - вновь и producere - производство, произведение] 1. Полигр., фото. Фотографическое или полиграфическое воспроизведение рисунка, картины, печатного текста и т.п. Р. многоцветных оригиналов. Фототехника - один из способ репродукции.

КОПИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. copja - обилие] 1. Точно соответствующее подлиннику воспроизведение чего-л. К. протокола. К. чертежа. **Картина сохранилась в нескольких копиях.** Снять копию трудовой книжки, диплома. Сделать копии с рукописи. // Снимок, отпечаток с негатива

Answer (score 1):

Что неправильно в предложении? Во-первых, неверно использовано слово *репродукция*, во вторых, не совсем корректно указан век.

**Представленная на выставке копия картины XVII века была выполнена современным художником.**

Пишите либо *XVII в.*, либо *XVII века*, либо *17-го века*.

> [Вопрос № 232663](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=232663)
>    Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно 20 век или ХХ век? И можно ли вообще использовать наращения типа 20-й век, 20-го века.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   **Для обозначения веков обычно используются римские цифры: XX век. При написании арабскими цифрами наращение нужно: 20-й век, 20-го века.**